# How to prove that $\mathcal{O}_{\sqrt{-11}}$ is a Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that $\mathcal{O}_{\sqrt{-11}}$ is a Euclidean domain, which denotes the domain of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$. I know that it is $-11 \equiv 1\mod 4$, so I can write it as $a+b\sqrt{-11}$ where $a$ and $b$ are both integers or both half-integers. But I have no idea how to proceed such a question. Any help or hint is appreciated!

Comment: Some references are given in [this survey article](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/NSJOM/Papers/38_1/NSJOM_38_1_137_154.pdf) about PIDs which are not Euclidean and related properties.

Comment: I don't have my copy of Hardy and Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, at hand, but I can get hold of it within a day or so.